# Como NÃO diferenciar maiúscula e minúscula com indexOf?

Tags: javascript

Tenho a seguinte função:

```
var name = $(".infoname").text();
if(name.indexOf("Carro")!=-1) {
    alert("existe");
} else {
    alert("não existe");
}
```

Como posso fazer para o `indexOf` não diferenciar maiúscula ou minuscula, exemplo "`Carro`", "`carro`".

Comment: `name` é o quê?

Comment: você pode usar var name = "carro"

Comment: name atualmente é var name = $(".infoname").text();

Comment: Dei uma pequena reformulada na pergunta. Se achar indevido, pode reverter na [revisão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/367970/revisions). ;D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Por que não funciona?

O exemplo a seguir definie duas variáveis string. As variáveis contém a mesma string, exceto que a segunda string tem letras maiúsculas. O primeiro método `log` exibe 19. Porém, **como o método** `indexOf` **é sensível a caixa**, a string "`cheddar`" não é encontrada em `myCapString`, portanto o segundo método `log` exibe -1.

```
var myString    = "brie, pepper jack, cheddar";
var myCapString = "Brie, Pepper Jack, Cheddar";

console.log('myString.indexOf("cheddar") é ' + myString.indexOf("cheddar"));    
// Exibe 19
console.log('myCapString.indexOf("cheddar") é ' + myCapString.indexOf("cheddar")); 
// Exibe -1
```

> Fonte: [String.prototype.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

---

## Alternativa #1:

**Forçar caixa baixa** na sua `string`:

```js
var name = 'CaRrO';
if(name.toLowerCase().indexOf("Carro".toLowerCase())!=-1) {
    alert("existe");
} else {
    alert("não existe");
}
```

Observe que tanto a `string` quanto o `searchValue` ficaram em caixa baixa, o que ajuda bastante na dinâmica.

---

## Alternativa #2:

Melhorando mais a dinâmica, você pode criar uma função para isto.

Veja meu exemplo:

```js
function in_str(string, value) {
    string = string.toLowerCase();
    value = value.toLowerCase();

    if (string.indexOf(value) != -1)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

console.log(
    in_str('Carro', 'Carro'), // true
    in_str('carro', 'CARRO'), // true
    in_str('caRRo', 'carro'), // true
    in_str('carro', 'caRRo'), // true
    in_str('MoTo', 'caRRo'), // false
    in_str('o Carro furou o pneu', 'caRRo') // true
);
```

---

## Alternativa #3:

A que eu considero **a melhor forma** e com **ainda mais dinâmica**, é definir um protótipo à classe `String`. Daí o uso vai ser **idêntico ao `.indexOf`** (exceto pelo nome do método).

Veja meu exemplo:

```js
String.prototype.indexOfCaseIns = function(searchValue, fromIndex) {
    return this.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchValue.toLowerCase(), fromIndex);
}

var str = 'Olá mundo!';

console.log(
    str.indexOfCaseIns('MunDO'), // 4
    str.indexOfCaseIns('world'), // -1
    str.indexOfCaseIns('Olá'), // 0
    str.indexOfCaseIns('ola'), // -1
    str.indexOfCaseIns('OLá'), // 0
    str.indexOfCaseIns('á munD'), // 2
    str.indexOfCaseIns('undo!') // 5
);
```

Repare que segue o mesmo sentido do `indexOf`: retorna `-1` se não encontrar ou o número do índice do valor buscado.

---

## Aplicando no seu código:

```
var name = $(".infoname").text();
if(name.indexOfCaseIns("Carro")!=-1) { // só trocar o método ;D
    alert("existe");
} else {
    alert("não existe");
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Faça o conteúdo da sua variável `name` e o parâmetro do `indexOf` ficarem em maiúsculo ou minúsculo.

**Maiúsculo**

```
// Exemplo em maiúsculo
if(name.toUpperCase().indexOf("CARRO") !== -1) {
    alert("existe");
} else {
    alert("não existe");
}
```

**Minúsculo**

```
// Exemplo em minúsculo
if(name.toLowerCase().indexOf("carro") !== -1) {
    alert("existe");
} else {
    alert("não existe");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Uma forma mais simples e que evita `indexOf`, `toLowerCase` e `toUpperCase` é usar expressão regular.

```
var name = $(".infoname").text();
if(name.match(/carro/i))) {
    alert("existe");
} else {
    alert("não existe");
}
```

Isso vai funcionar caso a string contenha `Carro`, `carro` ou não contenha nada.

Exemplo completo com todas as possibilidades:

```js
const str1 = "carro minusculo"
if (str1.match(/carro/i)) {
    console.log("existe")
} else {
    console.log("nao existe")
}

const str2 = "Carro maiúsculo"
if (str2.match(/carro/i)) {
    console.log("existe")
} else {
    console.log("nao existe")
}

const str3 = "sem"
if (str3.match(/carro/i)) {
    console.log("existe")
} else {
    console.log("nao existe")
}
```